# Simple SAML certificate not matching fingerprint

Tags: php, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I had a project dropped in my lap for SSO before another co-worker left the firm. We are using SimpleSamlPHP. I guess when the Idp forwards the user, they get a notice that says:

"Unable to find a certificate matching the configured fingerprint. Candidates: '***********************************'; certFingerprint: '*******************************'."

Please note I added the ***** in the place of displaying the real fingerprint or candidates.

I don't understand what does this really means, or what should I do. The certFingerprint in the error matches our metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php

```
Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] Backtrace:
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] 0 /var/www/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:180 (N/A)
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] Caused by: SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Unable to find a certificate matching the configured fingerprint. Candidates: '**********************'; certFingerprint: '************************'.
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] Backtrace:
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] 5 /var/www/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:116 (sspmod_saml_Message::findCertificate)
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] 4 /var/www/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:165 (sspmod_saml_Message::checkSign)
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] 3 /var/www/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:556 (sspmod_saml_Message::processAssertion)
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] 2 /var/www/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:528 (sspmod_saml_Message::processResponse)
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] 1 /var/www/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:81 (require)
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] 0 /var/www/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:135 (N/A)
    Aug 13 08:37:53 518537-web5 simplesamlphp[20692]: 3 [20fd4d449a] Error report with id 40d74688 generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

x509 public certificates or its fingerprint can be published. You only have to take care of not publish private keys so you don't need to put the ****

It seems that you have configured your IdP-remote metadata with a certFingerprint
instead of a certificate, so it will never look at the certificates in
the cert-directory.

From this output, it looks like your certFingerprint option is set
incorrectly. Either correct it, or replace the certFingerprint option
with either a 'keys'-option (which you get from the XML metadata
parser), a 'certData'-option or a 'certificate'-option.

Get more info at simpleSAMLphp documentation:
https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-reference-idp-remote#section_1